# files get uploaded just before they get cancelled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Got a little situation here where I am trying to cancel a file's upload. What I have done is stated that if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, then it will simply remove the iframe so that it does not go to the page where it uploads the files into the server and inserts data into the database.

Now this works fine if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button in quickish time the problem I have realised though is that if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button very late, it sometimes doesn't remove the iframe in time meaning that the file has just been uploaded just before the user has clicked on the "Cancel" button.

So my question is that is there a way that if the file does somehow get uploaded before the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, that it deletes the data in the database and removes the file from the server?

Below is the image upload form:

```
<form action="imageupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target_image" onsubmit="return imageClickHandler(this);" class="imageuploadform" >
  <p class="imagef1_upload_process" align="center">
    Loading...<br/>
    <img src="Images/loader.gif" />
  </p>
  <p class="imagef1_upload_form" align="center">
    <br/>
    <span class="imagemsg"></span>
    <label>Image File: <input name="fileImage" type="file" class="fileImage" /></label><br/>
    <br/>
    <label class="imagelbl"><input type="submit" name="submitImageBtn" class="sbtnimage" value="Upload" /></label>
  </p>
  <p class="imagef1_cancel" align="center">
    <input type="reset" name="imageCancel" class="imageCancel" value="Cancel" />
  </p>
  <iframe class="upload_target_image" name="upload_target_image" src="#" style="width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

Below is the jquery function which controls the "Cancel" button:

```
$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
    $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
    $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
    return stopImageUpload(2);
});
```

Below is the php code where it uploads the files and inserts the data into the database. The form above posts to this php page "imageupload.php":

```
<body>
<?php

include('connect.php');

session_start();

$result = 0;


//uploads file
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
"ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
$result = 1;

//set up the INSERT SQL query command to insert the name of the image file into the "Image" Table
$imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
VALUES (?)";

//prepare the above SQL statement
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($imagesql)) {
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//bind the parameters (these are the values that will be inserted) 
$insert->bind_param("s",$img);

//Assign the variable of the name of the file uploaded
$img = 'ImageFiles/'.$_FILES['fileImage']['name'];

//execute INSERT query
$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
  // Handle query error here
}

//close INSERT query
$insert->close();

//Retrieve the ImageId of the last uploded file
$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id; 

//Insert into Image_Question Table (be using last retrieved Image id in order to do this)
$imagequestionsql = "INSERT INTO Image_Question (ImageId, SessionId, QuestionId)  
VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 

//prepare the above SQL statement
if (!$insertimagequestion = $mysqli->prepare($imagequestionsql)) { 
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here 
  echo "Prepare statement err imagequestion"; 
} 

//Retrieve the question number
$qnum = (int)$_POST['numimage'];

//bind the parameters (these are the values that will be inserted) 
$insertimagequestion->bind_param("isi",$lastID, 'Exam', $qnum); 

//execute INSERT query
$insertimagequestion->execute(); 

if ($insertimagequestion->errno) { 
  // Handle query error here 
} 

//close INSERT query
$insertimagequestion->close();

?>

<!--Javascript which will output the message depending on the status of the upload (successful, failed or cancelled)-->

<script>
    window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');
</script>
</body>
```

UPDATE:

Below is the php code "cancelimage.php" where I want to delete the cancelled file from the server and delete the record from the database. It is set up but not finished, can somebody finish it off so I can retrieve the name of the file and it's id using $_SESSION?

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include('connect.php');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}


//remove file from server
unlink("ImageFiles/...."); //need to retrieve file name here where the ... line is

//DELETE query statement where it will delete cancelled file from both Image and Image Question Table
$imagedeletesql = " DELETE img, img_q 
FROM Image AS img 
LEFT JOIN Image_Question AS img_q 
ON img_q.ImageId = img.ImageId 
WHERE img.ImageFile = ?"; 

//prepare delete query
if (!$delete = $mysqli->prepare($imagedeletesql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$delete->bind_param("s",$img);

//execute DELETE query
$delete->execute();

if ($delete->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

//close query
$delete->close();

?>
```

Can you please provide an sample code in your answer to make it easier for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, like said in my previous answer, you could use the `$_SESSION` to store `$lastID` and `$ImageFile`.

#### For example, after `$lastID = $mysqli->insert_id;` insert the following:

```
$_SESSION['lastID'] = $lastID;
$_SESSION['ImageFile'] = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"];
```

This will store `lastID` and `ImageFile` in the session.

#### in `cancelimage.php` you put the following:

```
unlink("ImageFiles/" . $_SESSION['ImageFile']); 

$delete = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM Image WHERE id = ?');
$delete->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['lastID']);
$delete->execute();
```

#### Now add an action to the cancel button that updates the source of the iframe to `cancelimage.php`

But there is a risk, because if the user has uploaded a file before, uploads a new one but the file didn't get through (so the session vars are not set) then the previous file will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get it back to you and comment back to you on the outcome. Don't worry about the possiblity of the previous file being deleted if user uploaded file before because I did not include it in my question code but in my code I stated that if the file already exists in server, then perform a count and add a number. E.g If I already has tulips.png and I upload the same file again, that file becomes tulips_2.png, upload again then its tulips_3.png and etc.

Comment: Hey thanks mans, that has worked brilliantly :)

Answer (score 1):

Well since your using PDO you can use:

```
$insert->rollBack();
```

to roll back the recent insert. and find the file uploaded and use:

```
unlink('test.html');
```

check out these links for more information on `rollBack` and `unlink`

- [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)
- [rollBack](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php)

Comment: Hi, the only issue I have is that I only want to do the rollback if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, if the user hasn't clicked on the cancel button, then obviously the file gets uploaded, but if they click on the cancel button, then I want it to perform the unlink. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: i would store the file name into session variable $_SESSION["nameofupload"], then i would asynchronously go to another php page undo.php, and look for the session cookie i need and unlick then.

Comment: you put this into the Cancel Button's `Click` Event

Comment: @Relentless So I have to do something like `$_SESSION[filenameupload] = $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);`, then in undo.php page, do `unlink($_SESSION[filenameupload])` and finally in jquery code in cancel button function, do I navigate to the undo.php page buy including this code `jQuery.ajax("undo.php");`

Comment: Almost - in the session put the file name, which is $_FILES["file"]["name"] i think, depends on what your name your input. and now that u know what the file name is, you can delete if from another php page

Answer (score 0):

If the `iframe` is removed and the callback to tell which file is uploaded isn't called, then it will be kinda hard to know which file to delete.

Although you could store the `$lastID` and the `$ImageFile` of the last uploaded file in the `$_SESSION` and request some other page which does lookup the file in the database en deletes the record and then deletes the file from disk.

I could provide some sample code, but my suggestion is that you revise your current code, make it somewhat more readable and fix the indentation..

An other solution is to explicitly abort the upload using the following function:

```
function abortUpload(){
    var iframeObj = $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").get(0);
    if (iframeObj.contentWindow.document.execCommand){ 
        // IE
        iframeObj.contentWindow.document.execCommand('Stop');
    }else{
        // other browsers
        iframeObj.contentWindow.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the about upload method you have showed me before and it didn't quite work and that's why I went to the remove iframe method. I will clean up and indent the current code above to make it easier for you and others to read. I will also provide some code which will perform the unlink() and the deletion of the record from the db. Are you able to manipulate the code to match your theory on using $_SESSION?

Comment: Code is cleaned up, indented and included delete query and unlink statement, can you see the codes and see where the neccessary changes are needed and provide your version in how to fix it?