# How to stop file being inserted into server

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [files get uploaded just before they get cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020459/files-get-uploaded-just-before-they-get-cancelled)

I have a situation when it comes to cancelling a file upload. What is suppose to happen is that if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, then it will go to script below and remove the file from the server and delete the file's records from the database:

cancelaudio.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

  unlink("AudioFiles/" . $_SESSION['AudioFile']);  //undefined notice

$delete = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM Audio WHERE AudioId = ?'); 
$delete->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['lastAudioID']); 
$delete->execute(); 

$deleteaud = $mysqli->prepare('DELETE FROM Audio_Question WHERE AudioId = ?'); 
$deleteaud->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['lastAudioID']); 
$deleteaud->execute(); 


?>
```

Now this is the situation I am having:

If I clean my cookies, it means obviously I have no files stored my $_SESSION variable. Now if I try to upload a file (first file) but then cancel it, then I get an undefined index notice for "AudioFile". This is fair as obviously I have no file stored in that $_SESSION variable. But the problem is that it does not perfrom the unlink() and DELETE statement in the code above so it will display the record of the file and still uploads it.

So what is happening is that until I have one file in the server and a file stored in the $_SESSION['AudioFile'], it would not remove the file from the server and and it would delete the record from the database.

So what my question is that what do I need to do so that if there is no file in the `$_SESSION['AudioFile']` and the user uploads and then cancels a file, how can I stop it from inserting the file into the server and inserting the database record?

Below is the code where it uploads the files and inserts the data into the database:

audioupload.php

```
<?php

session_start();

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// connect to the database
include('connect.php');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

$result = 0;

if( file_exists("AudioFiles/".$_FILES['fileAudio']['name'])) {
$parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileAudio']['name']);
$ext = array_pop($parts);
$base = implode(".",$parts);
$n = 2;

while( file_exists("AudioFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
$_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileAudio"]["tmp_name"],
"AudioFiles/" . $_FILES["fileAudio"]["name"]);
$result = 1;

}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileAudio"]["tmp_name"],
"AudioFiles/" . $_FILES["fileAudio"]["name"]);
$result = 1;
}

$audiosql = "INSERT INTO Audio (AudioFile) 
VALUES (?)";

if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($audiosql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

//Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$aud);

//Assign the variable
$aud = 'AudioFiles/'.$_FILES['fileAudio']['name'];

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();

$lastAudioID = $mysqli->insert_id;   

$_SESSION['lastAudioID'] = $lastAudioID; 
$_SESSION['AudioFile'] = $_FILES["fileAudio"]["name"]; 


$audioquestionsql = "INSERT INTO Audio_Question (AudioId, QuestionId)  
VALUES (?, ?)"; 

if (!$insertaudioquestion = $mysqli->prepare($audioquestionsql)) { 
// Handle errors with prepare operation here 
echo "Prepare statement err audioquestion"; 
} 

$qnum = (int)$_POST['numaudio'];

$insertaudioquestion->bind_param("iii",$lastAudioID, $qnum); 

$insertaudioquestion->execute(); 

if ($insertaudioquestion->errno) { 
// Handle query error here 
} 

$insertaudioquestion->close(); 



?>
```

Below is the HTML form for the file input:

```
<form action='audioupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_audio' onsubmit='return audioClickHandler(this);' class='audiouploadform' > 

Audio File: <input name='fileAudio' type='file' class='fileAudio' /></label><br/><br/><label class='audiolbl'> 

<input type='submit' name='submitAudioBtn' class='sbtnaudio' value='Upload' /></label>

<input type='hidden' class='numaudio' name='numaudio' value='" + GetFormAudioCount() + "' />

<label><input type='reset' name='audioCancel' class='audioCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>

<iframe class='upload_target_audio' name='upload_target_audio' src='#' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>
```

Finally below is the jquery function where if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button while the file is uploading, it will simply change the iframe source to "cancelaudio.php":

```
function startAudioUpload(audiouploadform){
$(audiouploadform).find('.audiof1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
$(audiouploadform).find('.audiof1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
sourceAudioForm = audiouploadform;

$(audiouploadform).find(".audioCancel").on("click", function(event) {
$('.upload_target_audio').get(0).contentwindow
$("iframe[name='upload_target_audio']").attr("src", "cancelaudio.php");
return stopAudioUpload();
});

return true;
}
```

Comment: @MarkBaker That duplicate question you are referring to different, in that question I was asking what is best way to delete database row and remove files when user has clicked cancel on a file that was just uploaded before the cancel. This question is asking that before a file has been stored in a session, if I try and cancel a file upload, then it still inserts the data and file into server

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your undefined index stuff, plus make your script a lot more robust, you SHOULD add error checking. Even a simple

```
if ($_FILES['fileAudio']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... successful upload ...
}
```

would reduce a lot of your problems. Right now your code simply assumes a successful upload, without even bothering to check if an upload was event attempted.

The various error codes for failure are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: OK I will test this and come back to you on the outcome. thanks :)

Comment: Was this code suppose to go into the "audioupload.php" page because I have done this but it still inserts data into database and stores file in server when I try to cancel first file upload after an empty `$_SESSION['AudioFile']` I still get undefined index for `AudioFile` in cancelaudio.php page